# How to fill a GridPanel with data from a database with Ext.Net?

Tags: database, connection-string, ext.net, gridpanel

I found [this example](http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/DataSource_Controls/SqlDataSource/) but am completely new to this and so it is too advanced for me... I understand what's going on in the view, but how and where am I supposed to actually connect to the database, with a username and password and all? What should my connectionString be in Web.config? What is "NorthwindConnectionString"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178303%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) actually helped me out a lot. I wasn't trying to connect to an ODBC database, but I didn't know that there was a wizard that would walk me through the steps! It figured everything out for me.

Answer (score 2):

The `NorthwindConnectionString` in the sample you linked to is configured in the `Web.config`. The following  MSDN documentation should help you step through connecting to a SQLDataSource, see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.connectionstring.aspx

As noted in the above link, the Connection String is added to the `<connectionStrings>` node of the Web.config. This connection string holds you database credentials.

**Example**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyNorthwind" connectionString="server=foehammer;database=Northwind;user=north;password=north;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Hope this helps.